# PHPUnit giving me Class "DOMDocument" not found

Tags: php, phpunit, domdocument

I had phpunit working and wanted to add xdebug and coverage so I installed xdebug. I got that done but now its saying "Class "DOMDocument" not found". I am using Ubuntu, PHP 8.0.16, PHPUnit 8.5.2. So just trying to find how to fix it.

[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
igbinary
imagick
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
redis
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules
Xdebug
Zend OPcache

Answer (score 0):

I found the install was a global. Once I uninstalled the global and installed a local via composer I was able to get it to work.